# Is there a site when I can get children's book recommendations based upon certain criteria?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I don't know if the question belongs in *Parenting*, *Fantasy and Science Fiction*, or neither.  I'm looking for reading recommendations for my four-year-old based upon what we have read recently.  Is there a Stack Exchange site where I could ask that?

Also, is this site the correct place to ask this (*the above*) question?

Comment: Interestingly, the question in the title (but not the questions in the body) would, I believe, be appropriate on [WebApps.se].

Comment: @mmyers That question would be closed at Web Apps. We don't accept "help me find a site" questions.

Answer (score 5):

No. Stack Exchange is a network of sites providing *the* answer to specific questions.

There is no such thing as the correct answer for 'what books should I read?' because;

- a) It is very subjective
- b) Whatever is 'good' now will be replaced by something better later, making any answers irrelevant
- c) there would be no way to legitimately mark one answer as 'Correct' - in that it provided the solution to your problem.

Think of Stack Exchange as a repository for Questions and their respective Answers. If you have a topic (such as Sci Fi) and think "Oh, I wonder why Episode 4 of Space Chuckers was able to be set 1,000,000 years after the pilot episode" then you can ask it there, and someone may have the answer. Then at a later date someone else has the same thought they can come to SciFi Stack Exchange and find the answer. And that answer will be correct for the whole time Stack Exchange is in existance.

That is what makes Stack Exchange sites so useful. Correct answers to very specific questions.

Comment: While to some extent I agree, this is a fairly precise speculation.  There are only so many other books at the same reading level and of the same caliber  as James and the Giant Peach ( a book we just finished reading ).  And though subjective, it ends up being subjective in the same way as say, "What is the best way to iterate over an array in Python?"

Answer (score 4):

Different Stack Exchange sites have different approaches to book-recommendation questions. Programming sites generally disallow them. On Mathematics they are [allowed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation?sort=newest&pageSize=50), if grudgingly, except for extremely vague ones ("the single math book everyone should read" wouldn't fly). Physics has a [resource recommendations policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4697) of their own. And so on.

Since the topic of your question pertains mostly to parenting, you could  asking on meta.Parenting about the acceptability of book recommendations there. (Unless there is already a discussion of this topic).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, we do not currently have a site that would recommend a *"similar to…"* reading suggestion for you.

That is largely because of how we scope Q&A sites — answering very *definitive* questions that can be answered authoritatively. There's *not* a lot of broad opinion and anecdotal sharing in this type of Q&A.

There is a *very* limited use case where certain sites might recommend a very, *verrrrry* specific product as a solution, assuming you could narrow down the problem statement enough to where someone might be able to answer it **authoritatively.** But not many sites have accepted this limited use case when you are asking to help find a specific product-solution. There are a few sites that offer broader hardware/software recommendations, but we are not likely to expand that premise to create lists of interesting reading material based on what you read recently.

Answer (score 1):

The only sites in Stack Exchange explicitly for getting recommendations are [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) (recently graduated) and [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) (recently launched in public beta). Your question obviously wouldn't fit there.

There is a proposal for [Website Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80273/website-recommendations) which is currently in the Commitment phase. A question looking for a website that could do recommendations would presumably fit there.

Finally, there is [Book Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87408/book-recommendations), a different proposal currently in the Definition phase.

Comment: The Book Recommendations proposal has died.